# Bot Framework names entities

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

In google's api.ai, to process such a sentence:

"What is John Doe's email?"

I create a prebuilt entity called "given-name" and "last-name" to get the name "John Doe"

How to do the same with Microsoft Bot Framework/Luis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ms LUIS you need to add utterances base on your questions, and assign entity in that phrase.
you can refer below links.

http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/4/Creating-Intelligent-Web-Applications-With-LUIS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/home

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: The first link helped a lot, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it with the Bot Framework, not directly. Bot Framework help you build your conversation flow but doesn't come with built-in NLU. You are likely to use [LUIS](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/language-understanding-intelligent-service-luis) (also [luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai/)) which it [supports natively](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/guides/understanding-natural-language/#navtitle) and do your intent detection and entity extraction there. You can also consume your api.ai agent from the Bot Framework if you like. I did that to support a language that LUIS doesn't speak yet (more details - http://www.pveller.com/integrating-bot-framework-with-api-ai/)

**UPDATE**

Expanding on my comment. Here's how I approached extracting a `contact` entity in one of my bot prototypes. These are JSON snippets from the exported LUIS model:

```
"entities": [
    {
      "name": "Contact"
    }
],
"model_features": [
    {
      "name": "Contact",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "John Smith,John Doe,Mary Jay,Robin Smith",
      "activated": true
    }
],
"utterances": [
   {
      "text": "please email to john smith and robin smith",
      "intent": "Email",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Contact",
          "startPos": 16,
          "endPos": 25
        },
        {
          "entity": "Contact",
          "startPos": 31,
          "endPos": 41
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how to do it with Luis.ai? I've been trying to create an entity but i couldnt find a solution. prebuilt entities seem like the way to go, but its missing the name type

Comment: There are no names in a pre build entity set, I believe. You would need to train on a set of questions each one asking about someone's email in a different way and mark the name part as an entity. Your own custom entity. If you know the people who the user might ask about (e.g. it's your enterprise directory or something) you can use the `phrase list`. That will teach LUIS to treat all these names as the *same* entity. Where it recognize one, it will recognize all others basically. I believe I did that once in one of my bot prototypes. I can dig up that LUIS model probably. Let me know